# What is the fastest to animate graphics along CoreAudio programming : CoreGraphics? CoreAnimation ? Cocos2D ? OpenGL?

Tags: graphics, ios, core-audio

I have a project for the iphone that use CoreAudio to play multiple files at the same time. So what is the fastest library/framework to animate graphics along CoreAudio programming : `CoreGraphics`? `CoreAnimation` ? `Cocos2D`? `OpenGL` ?

My needs are simple : loading, displaying, hiding, rotation images and panning some views.

Thanks.

André

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to know which of the specified frameworks can animate graphics fast enough to keep up with some audio. I would use Core Animation for this. Core Animation is a wrapper around OpenGL and therefore is very performance effective. It supports both 2D and 3D animations and all animation is hardware accelerated. Core Graphics is not for animating but for drawing, so you can rule that out. OpenGL is a possible candidate, but it is very low level and difficult to learn, so I wouldn't recommend. Furthermore, it is largely used for 3D animations. Cocos2D is a game framework and can be used for animation, but I don't recommend using it solely for animation if you are not also using it for an actual game.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense. Graphics is independent of audio.

Sounds like you could get away with animating properties on UIViews,  although if you need high performance you would want core animation.

actually, core animation is conceptually a better path, seeing as you probably don't need to respond to touch events.

That is what you want anyway. Core animation.